# POST call works on Postman but not on Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, post, postman

```
  Future<String> loginUser(User user) async {
var body = jsonEncode({
  'strlogin': user.email,
});
Response response = await post(SeguriSignAPIURL.loginUser,
    headers: headers,
    body: body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var decode = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return decode['token'];
} else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
  return '';
}
```

Hey! When I make this Post call on Postman I get a result, however when I run this code on flutter I get a 400 error. My headers:

```
  final headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
"Accept": "application/json",
```

};

Postman:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postman you do the request using form-data, but in your Flutter code, you pass json-encoded body.

You either need to use form-data in Flutter or update your server code to accept json content type.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the request to a Multipart request fixed the issue